# Xorg stutter/lag with 18.04, GTX 1070 with Nvidia proprietary drivers

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I was running Elementary OS Hera (based on Ubuntu 18.04) in dual boot for Deep Learning experiments. Installation of `nvidia-driver-440` and CUDA 10.0 went on without problems, but after performing a few experiments my system started to lag/stutter.

Every few milliseconds (at fixed intervals), the screen will hang for another few milliseconds before continuing at normal speed again.

I've previously tried using Pop!_OS (18.04 and 19.10) and Ubuntu 18.04, but I've experienced the same problem. I thought it was an issue with GDM/Gnome 3 so I installed Elementary OS + nvidia drivers, which temporarily fixed the problem, but it returned again.

**What else I've tried**

1. Running the default nouveau drivers somehow **removes the stutter**, but this isn't a proper solution since it doesn't support CUDA.
2. `nvidia-smi` shows no processes other than my window manager and Xorg. Both `htop` and `nvidia-smi` show minmal system resource usage.
3. Installing older versions of the driver such as `nvidia-driver-435` in the default 18.04 repos did not resolve the stuttering.
4. On my dual-booted Windows, there is no such lag so I don't think it is a hardware problem

**System Specs**
I'm running a i5-4590 with a GTX 1070

Please let me know if there are any logs I can check for this problem